# How to prove the circumferential angle is equal if the arcs are equal in equal circles?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

How to prove the circumferential angle is equal if the arcs are equal in equal circles?

[image]

The $\frown{A}{B}$ equals to $\frown{C}{D}$,
how to prove the $\angle{AFB}$ = $\angle{CED}$?

and why if $\angle{AFB}$ = $\angle{CED}$, then we know $\frown{A}{B}$ equals to $\frown{C}{D}$?

Comment: What you are looking for is called the inscribed angle theorem. It's shown, described and proven in the Wikipedia page [Inscribed angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle). This shows that for any $2$ arc sub-sections of the same length, the inscribed angle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are fife cases for the proof of the theorem about an inscribed angle.

In the case for the your picture we can make the following.

Let $O$ be a center of the circle.

Thus, $$\measuredangle CFD=\measuredangle OED-\measuredangle OEC=\frac{180^{\circ}-\measuredangle EOD}{2}-\frac{180^{\circ}-\measuredangle EOC}{2}=$$
$$=\frac{\measuredangle EOC-\measuredangle EOD}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\measuredangle DOC=\frac{1}{2}\measuredangle AOB=\measuredangle AFB.$$

Answer (score 0):

I will use the pure Euclidean Geometry.

If the arcs $AB$ and $CD$ are congruent, then, called $O$ the center of the circumference, the angles $AOB$ and $COD$ are also congruent. Therefore the circumferential angles are congruent, because they are congruent to half angles which are congruent, namely $AOB$ and $COD$.

Conversely, if the circumferential angles are congruent, then the angles $AOB$ and $COD$ are congruent, because they are congruent to the double of angles which are congruent (the circumference angles). So, since the angles with vertex in $O$ are congruent, also the correspondent arcs $AB$ and $CD$ are congruent. QED